# Auto Delete Address not working in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: java, jms, jndi, activemq-artemis

I'm having issues getting ActiveMQ Artemis to automatically delete a dynamic address when there it is no longer used.

Below is an excerpt from the `broker.xml`:

```xml
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address></expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <expiry-delay>10</expiry-delay>
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <max-size-messages>-1</max-size-messages>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-delete-queues>true</auto-delete-queues>
            <auto-delete-addresses>true</auto-delete-addresses>
            <auto-delete-created-queues>true</auto-delete-created-queues>
            <auto-delete-queues-message-count>-1</auto-delete-queues-message-count>
         </address-setting>
```

Below is the producer code that creates the topic:

```java
    /////////////////////////////////////
    //Constructor to establish connection
    /////////////////////////////////////
    
    public ActiveMQ(String amq_url) throws JMSException, NamingException{
        jndi_env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        jndi_env.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
        jndi_env.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, amq_url);
        ic = new InitialContext(jndi_env);
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
        this.connection = (ActiveMQConnection) connectionFactory.createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    }
    
    ///////////useTopic()///////////
    //create/select topic
    ////////////////////////////////    
    public void useTopic(String topicName) throws JMSException, NamingException{
        if (producer != null) producer.close();
        this.topic = (Destination) ic.lookup("dynamicTopics/"+topicName);
        this.producer = session.createProducer(topic);
    }

    public void closeConnection() throws JMSException{
        if (producer != null) producer.close();
        if (connection != null) connection.stop();
        if (session != null) session.close();
        if (connection != null) connection.close();
    } 

}
```

When the address is created in ActiveMQ Artemis it looks different than the other ones in the drop down list (e.g. TEST_SDCData vs ExpiryQueue).

[image: Addresses]

My coworker and I are unable to figure out why this specific address will not delete based on the above without restarting the ActiveMQ Artemis server. The console shows that there are no consumers or producers connected after I stop the program that creates the topic.  The topic has a message count of 0 based on the ActiveMQ Artemis web console.  Any thoughts?  I feel like I'm not setting a specific value that needs to be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell everything is working as designed. Let me explain...

When a JMS clients sends a message to a topic and `auto-create-addresses` is `true` then the broker will respond by creating an address named according to where the message was sent. However, since the JMS topic has no consumers the message will simply be dropped. This conforms with basic publish/subscribe semantics.

The address won't be deleted at this point because the broker knows that no consumers have ever been created on it and therefore it hasn't actually been functionally used. If the broker were to delete the address in this situation then it would have to re-create it immediately when another message was sent to it. It would end up creating and deleting the address over and over as messages were sent to it wasting valuable resources. The broker avoids this pathological situation by waiting until at least one consumer has been created on the address before deleting it (i.e. once the consumer disconnects).

The reason your address looks different from the "ExpiryQueue" and "DLQ" addresses in the web console is because those two addresses have queues on them. Your address as well as the "activemq.notifications" address have no queues.

If you're unclear on how addresses and queues relate to each other you can read more in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html).

Comment: Thank you Justin!  I will attach a consumer and see what happens.  I'm pretty sure it still doesn't delete when both are disconnected, but I will double check this today.  Will also double check my consumer code to make sure it properly disconnects.  I was under the impression it would delete after 30 seconds because that is what the scan interval is set to in the broker.xml

Comment: Thanks Justin.  This was indeed the case.   The error lies in my consumer program.  When I connected, then stopped the consumer, the address was deleted as intended.  There's a bug where the consumer isnt closing a connection.  When i stopped the consumer java program, the topic was deleted.